# SQL query converting varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT distinct 
    (Client_Name),
    AMC_Expiry as date,
    Dealer_Name,
    Location,
    Product_Type, Product_Name,
    Quantity, 
    Install_Date, Warranty_Expiry, AMC_Expiry,
    mail_sent,
    billing_by, callhandled_by   
FROM 
     amc 
WHERE   
    (datediff(day, cast(convert(datetime, AMC_Expiry, 103) as datetime),  
                   cast(convert(datetime, GETDATE(), 103) as datetime)) > '-30'   
    and datediff(day, cast(convert(datetime, AMC_Expiry, 103) as datetime),
                      cast(convert(datetime, GETDATE(), 103) as datetime))  < 1)     
    and mail_sent = 'N'   
    or (datediff(day, cast(convert(datetime, Warranty_Expiry, 103) as datetime),
                      cast(convert(datetime, GETDATE(), 103) as datetime)) > '-30'
    and datediff(day, cast(convert(datetime, Warranty_Expiry, 103) as datetime),
                      cast(convert(datetime, GETDATE(), 103) as datetime))  < 1) 
    and mail_sent = 'N'
```

Comment: and the question is...???

Answer (score 2):

First, you seem to misunderstand `select distinct`. `DISTINCT` is *not* a function. It is part of a clause that applies to *all* columns.

Second, you are doing absurd things like:

```
cast(convert(datetime,GETDATE(),103) as datetime))
```

Why would you be taking a `datetime` value, converting it to a `datetime` and then re-convert it to a `datetime`.

In addition, you have a comma in the `WHERE` clause, which makes no sense. And, you have integer constants in single quotes.

Your query has more problems than the one you mention.

Comment: SELECT distinct (Client_Name),
                AMC_Expiry as date,
                Dealer_Name,
                Location,
                Product_Type,
                Product_Name,
                Quantity, 
                Install_Date,
                Warranty_Expiry,
                AMC_Expiry,
                mail_sent,
                billing_by,
                callhandled_by   
FROM amc it is running properly after that it is coming index out of range and i am converting varchar to datetime